# Differential Identity $\nabla\phi(t,x)\cdot f(x)=f(\phi(t,x))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $\frac{d}{dt} x=f(x)$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$, be smooth, and we let the flow of the ODE be $\phi(t,x)$. Show that:

$\nabla\phi(t,x)\cdot f(x)=f(\phi(t,x))$

This was in my ODE class when we talked about Hamiltonian systems last semester. The professor, said that it was easy, and we should verify it ourselves. I forgot about it until looking through my notes and am now trying to prove it.

My attempt

$f(\phi(t,x))=\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t,x)$. Thus, $\frac{d}{dt}\phi(t,x)=\nabla\phi(t,x)\cdot \frac{d}{dt}x+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi(t,x)$, by the chain rule. If I could say that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi(t,x)=0$ it would be good, but I don't think I can. Moreover, we also know that the flow has the group property $\phi(\phi(t,x),s)=\phi(t+s,x)$. I think one would want to use this. However, I am stuck. Any hints?

Comment: What is the relation between $\nabla \phi(t,x)\cdot f(x)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}(t,x)$, knowing that $f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ ?

Comment: You want to start by computing the LHS by plugging in $f(x)=\frac{d}{dt}x$. Or that :)

Comment: Why there is not a term $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(t,x)$ ?